# Optimize mysql query: products <- N:N -> categories

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to do this query in a more optimized way?

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from products p
INNER JOIN `products_categories` AS `pc` ON p.id = pc.products_id
where pc.categories_id = 87
```

My schema is simple: products, categories and a N:N join table: products_categories. Products are about 400000 rows. products_categories is about 600000. Products with category = 87 are about 18000. Using explain gives:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  pc  index   products_id products_id 8   NULL    612469  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   stagingbagthis.pc.products_id   1   Using index
```

It seems to me that the first line where rows = 612469 is not a very good sign. So, can this query be optimized in any way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index on `products_categories.categories_id` so that the `WHERE` clause can be optimized.

Comment: I already have an index of (products_id, categories_id). But that one isn't a good one?

Comment: No, that won't help. A composite index can be used to optimize a prefix of the index, but `categories_id` is not a prefix of that. If you change it to `(categories_id, products_id)` it will work, but then queries that look only for `products_id` will be slow. So you need the composite index and also a single index for whichever column is second in the composite.

Comment: Both this suggestion and @Gordon Linoff were implemented but the main improvement was adding the index. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What if you removed the `products` table:

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*)
from products_categories` `pc` 
where pc.categories_id = 87;
```

For this, you would need an index on `products_categories(categories_id)`, or similar index where `categories_id` is the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from products p
    INNER JOIN `products_categories` AS `pc` 
        ON p.id = pc.products_id and pc.categories_id = 87
```

Also check the cardinality of your indexes we have found cases where the cardinality gets out of whack and we need to analyze the tables to get our execution plans back in line.

Comment: There's no difference. In an INNER JOIN, you should only have conditions that relate the tables in the `ON` clause. Single-table conditions are equivalent to `WHERE`.

Comment: I have had cases in more complex queries where moving the single table conditions has changed the execution plan.